# Why is the ground state energy of the Heisenberg XXZ Model unbounded for some values of $J$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, spin-models

At the moment, I'm looking at numerically studying the Heisenberg XXZ model. The Hamiltonian is given below:
$$
H=\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\left(J S_j^z S_{j+1}^z+\frac{K}{2}(S_j^+S_{j+1}^-+S_j^-S_{j+1}^+)\right)
$$
where $J$ and $K$ are coupling parameters. I was able to calculate the matrix form of the Hamiltonian fine, but I have a question:

I recently calculated the ground eigenstate $v_0$, and from here calculated the ground state energy $\epsilon_0=\langle v_0|{\bf H}|v_0\rangle$. Note that the Hamiltonian matrix ${\bf H}$ is normalized. When I set $K=1$ and plot $\epsilon_0$ vs. $J$, I find that, for $J<-1$ and $J>1$, the ground state energy is $-1$. However, for $-1<J<1$, I get bizarre behavior - namely, the energy approaches negative infinity as $J\rightarrow 0$. Is this expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong? What's causing this?

Comment: Hi user55394 - we prefer to have one question per post. I've edited your other questions out, but you can post them separately. (Question #2 might not be appropriate for this site, though; it's too open-ended, I think.)

Comment: The XXZ model as $J\to 0$ becomes equivalent to a free Fermi lattice system via the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation). This certainly has a finite ground state energy, so it looks like you have made a mistake somewhere. I would suggest calculating the ground state in the $J=0$ limit analytically, using the JW transformation, and then comparing with your numerical results to find the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly unexpected, for as Mark Mitchison commented the $J=0$ Heisenberg model is equivalent to free fermions in one dimension. Moreover I suspect that something is amiss even before that, for the $J=-1$ is the ferromagnetic model and $J=+1$ the antifferomagnetic one, and certainly they have different ground state energies.

In fact, for $J\leq -1$ is trivial that the ground state consists of all spins aligned, the state $|\uparrow...\uparrow \rangle $. In this case is easy to verify from the Hamiltonian that the energy of such ground state is $E_F=\frac{JN}{4}$, where I assume you're working with spin one-half.

Now the Heisenberg XXZ model is exactly solvable by means of [Bethe Ansatz](http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/introbethe.html). Unfortunately the Bethe Ansatz is not particularly nice for analytical calculations, but it is very easy to evaluate the ground state in the thermodynamical limit $N\rightarrow \infty$. I'll just quote the result, which is a straighforward generalization from the one in [Giamarchi's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198525001).

For $-1\leq J\leq 1$ the ground state has total spin zero, and denoting by $E$ the ground state energy and $E_F$ the ferromagnetic ground state energy, we have in the thermodynamical limit that

\begin{equation}
\frac{E-E_F}{N}=-\frac{(J+1)}{2}0.693-\frac{(J-1)}{2}0.307,
\end{equation}

where the constants $0.693$ and $0.307$ are obtained by numerical integration. For long chains, say $N$ larger than $10$, the thermodynamical limit should be a good approximation, so you can use it to compare with your numerical results.